# Connect to Dynamic CRM using Java Http Client

Tags: java, dynamics-crm-2011, httpclient, office365

I have been trying to connect to CRM using the below Java code, but I am getting an authentication issue.

```
package com.raj;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class MSDynaOData {

/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

NTCredentials creds = new NTCredentials("XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXX", "", "");
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

HttpHost target = new HttpHost("XXXXXXXXX", 80, "http");
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

// Execute a cheap method first. This will trigger NTLM authentication
String url = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/Account";
url += "?$select=Name";
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, localContext);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println(" Status :: " + response.getStatusLine());

for (Header header : response.getAllHeaders()) {
System.out.println(header.getName() + " : " + header.getValue());
}

System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(entity.getContent()));
}
}
```

Response contains :

```
Constants.TokenizedStringMsgs.GENERIC_ERROR = "<H1>Sorry, but we're having trouble           signing you in</H1><p>Please try again in a few minutes. If this doesn't work, you might     want to contact your admin and report the following error: #~#ErrorCode#~#.</p>";
  Constants.TokenizedStringMsgs.UPN_DISAMBIGUATE_MESSAGE = "It looks like #~#MemberName_LS#~# is used with more than one account. Which account do you want to use?";
```

I am able to login to CRM 2011 online through the credentials used in Java code successfully, but when I used same credentials in the code I am getting the above login issue response.

Please let me know if I am missing anything in the above code.

Comment: Does your target specify the organisation you are trying to connect to?